# HTML attribute value question

Tags: html

what does it mean a value that contains no U+000A LINE FEED (LF) or U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) characters. Can some one explain in layman's terms and give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it means a string that doesn't contain a line feed or carriage return character, like `this_one`.

```
here_is
one_that_
does
```

#### Update

> I got this info from w3.org

Please link to this. I thought it may have been *don't use them in your HTML attributes*, but I just validated a page with a multiline `title` attribute with the W3C validator.

Comment: Not all but __some__ attributes disallow LF/CR in their values.

Comment: @Mark Cidade Which ones (some like `href` seem obvious)? Thanks

Comment: For example, the `value` attribute for the `input` element, and the `placeholder` attribute for `textarea`.

Comment: @Mark Cidade That makes total sense. I wish the OP had linked where they read that, for some context.

Answer (score 1):

When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a text editor to go to the next line, an invisible LINE FEED and/or CARRIAGE RETURN character is inserted.

Some HTML attributes cannot have any line breaks in their values, according to the specification,

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with HTML attributes or values. LF and CR are end of line characters. [Wikipedia has an excellent article about them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-line#Representations). What are you trying to accomplish and where are you getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, common commands will include an element, an attribute and a value.  For example, in `<A HREF ="somevalue">` A is the element, HREF is the attribute and somevalue is the value.

When you say values cannot have a carriage return or a line feed, then the value statement should not look like this:

```
<A HREF ="somevalue ENTER
somevalue continuing after a carriage return and line feed"></A>
```

Avoid that.  Instead, that same information should be typed, letting the code wrap around on its own.